Sculpt Mode - Transform Brush - How to Uniform Scale (All Axes)
Is it possible to perform a uniform scale operation within the Transform brush? I've only been able to scale for individual axes, and had to use Scale brush for uniform scale.
Other 3D programs usually provide a way to perform uniform scaling in their transform (gizmo) operators, which is why I assumed that I must be missing something with Blender's transform brush in sculpt mode.
I'm not asking for another method (such as Scale or Mesh Filter brushes) to apply uniform scaling, I'm asking if it is possible with the Transform brush.


If you click on the white circle and drag, then press 'S' before lifting the mouse button it will change to Scale mode. Pressing 'G' instead will change into translation mode and pressing 'R' into rotation mode

The method you've provided indeed works and has provided a huge mental relief! I've not been able to get an answer to this on Discord channels or on reddit, and search engines did not provide any help either. Since I don't have "upvote" privileges, a confirmation of the provided solution and thank you message felt necessary, thank you.

Np. With a lot of tools, you get the different hotkey you can use with them on the bottom of the screen when you activate them if you don't release the mouse button. They are also useful with tools in edit mode
